# How does Windows recognize the Ethernet Networkname?

Tags: windows, local-area-network

I try to understand, how Windows recognize the correct LAN\Ethernet Networkname shown on the Network Tray Icon or in the Network Settings.

On the DHCP Server the "015 DNS Domain Name Option" is set to: MySubDomain.MyDomain.intra, but the Network on Windows will be recogized as "MyDomain.intra" and not MySubDomain.MyDomain.intra.
In the IPConfig it shows also the "Primary Dns Suffix" as "MySubDomain.MyDomain.intra.".

[Network Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpy6E.png)

Any idea...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the network adapter properties IPv4 properties? Fairly basic network 101 stuff there.

Comment: The IPv4 settings are correct and the IP is obtained via DHCP.
What does this have to do with my question?

Comment: It is possible to set the domain name in the network adapter properties. What is your understanding of where "Windows recognize the network name" from?

Comment: This is clear that it could be set by GPO or manualy etc. But it's not...
Its showing the Name (in my example) "myDomain.intra" without that anything has been set by GPO or manually... the Question is... why only "MyDomain.intra" and not the full Domain "MySubDomain.MyDomain.intra".....

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the exact process used by Windows to determine network name is not officially documented. However, it is known that Windows uses AD domain forest name in some way to determine network profile. This might be the reason you see forest domain as name for the network adapter.

> The Network Location Awareness (NLA) service expects to be able to enumerate the domain's forest name to choose the right network profile for the connection.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/computer-cant-identify-network#cause

Also, you might want to check registry keys mentioned in the article to make sure it is not an outdated cache issue

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Nla\Cache`